# Is this a Firefox bug? CSS after this input[type=""] rule isn't being read at all

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm about to launch a site and got to the browser testing phase, then opened it up in Firefox and it was completely broken. I looked at it a week or two ago and it was fine, so I had a feeling it was a single thing causing a lot of errors, and not a whole heap of browser incompatibility issues.

Anyway after a bit of debugging I found that all the CSS after this rule (below) wasn't loading at all. I can't see anything wrong with this rule. I've also determined that it's not the content of the rule (-webkit-appearance: none), but the input[type=""] selectors.

```
/* Remove rounded corners in mobile webkit browsers */
input[type="text",
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="search"],
select,
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be causing Firefox issues?

For now I've just made it the last rule which is fine because this rule isn't aimed at Firefox. But I'm really curious as to why it's happening..?

Comment: is it just a typo that you left out the closing bracket here? `input[type="text",`

Comment: The missing bracket could be a big issue, `]`.

Comment: Wow, I scoured that multiple times and didn't see the missing bracket. Thanks guys. I feel stupid now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an unclosed bracket on the first line: `input[type="text",` should read `input[type="text"],`.

Firefox usually stops parsing CSS files when it encounters a syntax error, which is why the rest of the rules in the file aren't applied.

Comment: That was also me who commented :) ... I deleted it after you fixed it.

Comment: Firefox doesn't stop parsing CSS when it encounters a syntax error.  It does what http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors says, which is quite a bit more complicated than "stop parsing".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a Firefox bug, in error handling. I have now reported it in Bugzilla as [Bug 810651](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=810651): Missing “]” in selector causes rest of style sheet to be ignored.

If you check your CSS using the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), its report is not very descriptive in this case, just “parse error”, but at least you will see that there is an error in your CSS code. Besides, you look closer, you’ll see that it reports:

1   input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], input[type="tel"], input[type="email"], input[type="search"], select, textarea  Parse Error [text]

The piece of CSS code here refers to what Firefox tried to parse, so we need to look at code before it, because this affects the parsing mode. The previous part is `input[type="text",`, so Firefox is apparently processing all the rest as if it were inside the attribute selector part that starts with “[”. Such error handling is incorrect, because by the [error handling rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors), the browser should skip the rest of the *statement* only.

Naturally, the way to circumvent this bug is to fix your CSS syntax error.

Comment: Marked your bug invalid; the behavior of Firefox here is correct per the CSS error handling rules... and you even quoted the relevant part of those rules in the bug!